# Pivot a list of data without aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have the following dataset shown below which determines access privileges for different users within our database. However I need to convert this into a dataset where the user_code are column headers and the Y / N data are field values.

Do you know how I would go about achieving this within MSSQL? I had a look into PIVOT function but it seems that that won't do the job for me, unless I'm missing something major!

Thanks in advance.

Example of my desired output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|        Area         | AP | AM | AGN | AH | AUT | AR | etc...|
---------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Accounts Team       |  N |  Y |  N  |  Y |  N  | Y  | ..... |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Administration Team |  Y |  N |  Y  |  N |  N  | N  | ..... |
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just curious, why do you think PIVOT won't work?  This is exactly what PIVOT is for.

Comment: Have you tried the PIVOT function or not?

Comment: You can use `PIVOT`, you just need to use the correct aggregation function (which in this case could be `MIN` or `MAX`)

Comment: You are right. Normal pivot is limited, in this case `User_Code` which is spreading element becomes limited. You will have to use dynamic pivot. **For ex:** http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/pivoting-data

Answer (score 1):

Just use `MAX` or `MIN` as your aggregate function. They are usually meaningless when applied to strings, but satisfy the condition of the PIVOT statement.

```
SELECT    user_name,
          [AP],[AM],[AGN],...
FROM      my_table
PIVOT     (
             MAX(access_ind) FOR user_code IN ([AP],[AM],[AGN],...)
          ) pvt
```

The trouble is that if you have more than one access entry for a user, you must decide which one to keep.

Comment: This is not what he wants. In this normal pivot, Spreading element becomes limited, in this case `User_Code`. He will have to use dynamic pivoting.